# Laravel 5.5 Deploying issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I setup my laravel 5.5 project on shared hosting when i want to access it gives me the error

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/shiners/storage/framework/sessions/tN0Ru2VK3Cvz0ySLZOKYGIebD0WE6lfQ1tD77xVs): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that the hosting provider did not provide ssh access so i won't be able to do from ssh command line. 
Please help..

Comment: It is because composer is probably not installed. I don't think it is possible to run laravel without command line.

Comment: @B-Noid that's not true. Its possible to run Laravel without command line, but the composer install command will need to be run locally then copied to the web server using ftp.

Comment: @Adbdullah, you must set permissions on your folders and files, but since you don't have ssh access, you will need to set it manually using the ftp client.